# Two-way communication between BigQuery and Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

Is two-way communication between BigQuery and Google Sheets possible?
In other words, if add a row or modify an entry in Google Sheets it reflects in the corresponding table in BigQuery, and vice versa (no schema changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one-way connections in either direction, but not two-way from both.

**From Google Sheets to Google BigQuery:**

You can define a Sheets file as an [external data source in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive). This way, any updates to the sheet will be reflected back in any queries from BigQuery.

*Setting this up from the command-line:*

1. Authenticate with Google Drive scopes:

```
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
```

2. Get the Drive URI of your sheet.
3. Create the [external table definition file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition#google_drive_2):

```
bq mkdef \
--noautodetect \
--source_format=source_format \
"drive_uri" \
path_to_schema_file > /tmp/mytable_def.json
```

Modify the file with a text editor with any addition options.

4. Create the [external table to query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table).

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=/tmp/mytable_def.json mydataset.mytable
```

Modifying an external table from BigQuery is not supported.

**From BigQuery to Sheets:**

Use [Connected Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9702507?hl=en) to visualize BigQuery data with Google Sheets.

Updating BigQuery data via connected sheets is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can add rows to a google sheet and see the results reflected in BQ when you query.  Additionally you can add columns to the sheet, and make the appropriate schema changes in BQ and see the resulting values.

You cannot though run DML from BigQuery that would result in additional rows being added to a google sheet.

Comment: Correct, BQ is able to query sheets but not write to it.  Conversely Sheets is able to read from BQ via the BigQuery connector, but not execute DML